# Full view on right livelihood

Tags: personal-practice, karma, lay-buddhism, right-livelihood

I have seen some questions on what the scope of right/wrong livelihood is, however most of the questions I have seen only touch on a specific point, so I would like to consolidate these questions and include new ones, so we can have a better view to comment on:

1. If I work on a controversial industry (alcohol/weapons/pesticide/tobacco...) but doing a job not directly related to the product, not making, not selling, not marketing it (HR/Finance for instance...). Is that a breach of right livelihood?
2. If I work in a meat business in a simple position, let's say a cashier in mcdonalds selling burgers, is that a breach of right livelihood?
3. If I'm a shareholder of such companies and earn dividends (mcdonalds, brewers, etc) is that a breach?
4. If I work in a controversial business and tried to leave it several times, but couldn't find anything else, and was dependent on it to live, is that right livelihood?

Where are the borders drawn for right livelihood in cases like these?